# Program that outputs text via another program that the first one codes for

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was just trying to come up with ideas of programs I could write, as I learn python. And then I thought would it be possible to write a program, that takes input from the user, and then writes that into a .py file as code.

If we were to run that .py file, we should get the output we put in like how the `print("Hello World")` works.

Any ideas as to how this could be written?

Edit: I am still learning, so please explain like I know nothing but basic print code and a couple math operations :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```py
file = open("test.py", "w")  # Open a file for writing(overwrites previous files) and puts it in the file variable
file.write("print('Hello world')")  # .write() adds content of print('Hello world') 
file.close()  # Close the file
```

You can use:

```py
file = open("test.py", "w")
file.write("print('Hello world')\n")
file.write("print('Hello world2')\n")
file.close()
```

For multi-line code

Comment: I Get it now. Thank you. But, what does "w" do?

Comment: @CustardJesus `w` means write and `r` means read. If this is the correct answer mark it as correct